# How to create a dimension table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 data source, each has its own dimensions and fact table.
Both data sources have a dimension called "Country"

Dimension 1 for Data Source 1

```
Country | Country Order 
Australia | 1
Singapore | 2
Indonesia | 3
..
```

Dimension 2 for Data Source 2

```
Country | Country Order 
AUSTRALIA | 1
SINGAPORE | 2
INDONESIA | 3
..
```

Data Source 1 Dimension Table 1 has more countries compared to Data Source 2 Dimension Table 2.

I am building a dashboard and i want to use country as a common filter, meaning one filter that can filter 2 different fact table.

I have tried creating a new table that contain one column with all the distinct values and tried to create relationship to both dimension table but it keep promoting me an error - circular dependency.

Any other methods that can work for this?
Thanks!

Comment: How have you created your new table that contains one column with all the distinct values? In Power Query, I trust? If you've instead attempted to create that table in DAX then I can see that causing issues with circular dependencies.

Comment: as my connection is direct query for both data source, i am unable to use power query to create the table with distinct value hence i used DAX to create. after creating the table, do i need to form relationship?

Comment: It might be possible to create a static table which you can guarantee will comprise all entries from both tables. For example, if, as in your example, the field in question is a list of countries of the world, then that can easily be generated. It would not matter if this table contained some entries which do not exist in your two data sources. Failing that, I'm not sure how you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I find it best to create my dimension tables in PQ. Create a new query named country_dimension that is an append of your two fact tables. Remove all other columns and then remove duplicates. You can then use this in your model and you won't get any circular dependency problems.

Comment: my connection is direct query for both data source, i am unable to use power query to create the table with distinct value hence i used DAX to create. Is there any other methods?

Comment: I second what David suggested, a fact table that combines both dimension tables. Why a direct query for both data sources?

Comment: @Dolunaykiz its in direct query mode because unable to have live connection to connect to multiple data sources